# Write new column with title and numbers in a specific line in a text file in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to finish this problem here. I have an file that has this description:

```
Title Title Title
Data: DD/MM/YYYY
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
 1    2    3    4     5    -    N   
 8    9   10    11   12    -    N
```

What I need to do, is to add a new column right next to the var7, called var8 and insert numbers from a list.
Like that:

```
Title Title Title
Data: DD/MM/YYYY
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7  var8
 1    2    3    4     5    -    N     42
 8    9   10    11   12    -    N    202
```

So far I've done this:

```
new_list = ['42', '202', '133', '144', '373', '277']


# Writing new row in .txt file

with open("dados.txt") as input_file, open("dados2.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(input_file):
        line = line.rstrip()
        number = new_list[lineno % len(new_list)]
        line += ' ' + number
        output_file.write(line + '\n')
```

My file output is this:

```
Title Title Title 42
Data: DD/MM/YYYY 202
var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7    133
 1    2    3    4     5    -    N     144
 8    9   10    11   12    -    N     373
```

Note that I can't add the new title and those numbers start to print at the first line of the .txt file
Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you have to do this in base Python (and not pandas, which makes this a one-liner)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_list = ['42', '202', '133', '144', '373', '277']

with open("dados.txt") as input_file, open("dados2.txt", "w") as output_file:
    # preprocessing
    output_file.write(input_file.readline())
    output_file.write(input_file.readline())
    output_file.write(input_file.readline()[:-1] + " var8\n")    # after this the pointer is at line 4

    for lineno, line in enumerate(input_file):
        line = line.rstrip()
        number = new_list[lineno % len(new_list)]
        line += '  ' + number                                    # two spaces look good
        output_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to adjust `new_list` so that it looks like this: `new_list = [' ', ' ', 'var8','42', '202', '133', '144', '373', '277']`, with 2 empty strings (then `var8`) which writes them to the end of the first 2 lines, then `var8` to the wanted thrid line. This may not be as good as edusankedt's way, but it still adds `var8` to the wanted line.

Comment: It is a good idea. Though those strings are not empty, adding a space in the end might cause a lot of misbehavior because they can't be seen but are read by python.

Comment: Ahhh, getcha, didn't think of that.

Comment: Yeah! That was exactly what I did! Thanks, guys!